# how to merge csv files columns start with 01, 02, 03.... till 100

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using below code to merge two csv files but in both files '1stcolumn' contains numbers start with 01, 02, 03.... till 100 but when is trying to merge two files its merge from 10, 11 12... till 100. why 01 to 09 rows not getting merge. How to merge this full row from 01 to 100 can anyone tell me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv('1stfile.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('2ndfile.csv')

print(data1)

data1['1stcolumn'] = data1['1stcolumn'].astype(str)
data2['1stcolumn'] = data2['1stcolumn'].astype(str)

output1 = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='1stcolumn', how='inner')
print(output1)

output1.to_csv('finalfile.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Can you please post an example input and output csv file? Maybe a smaller but similar version if the original is too big.

Comment: check csv files screen short I have added.

Comment: @Chetan please post text, not screenshots; see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `1stcolumn` was converted to `int` in one file and `str` in another. You don't get any error on `merge` because you are converting the column to string but I think it's too late for that.
Try to do this when the data is loaded and don't let Pandas infer the data type:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('1stfile.csv', dtype={'1stcolumn': str})
data2 = pd.read_csv('2ndfile.csv', dtype={'1stcolumn': str})
```

In your previous code, if you comment out the two lines where you use `astype`, the `merge` operation raise an exception like:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

If your data is '01', '02', '03', Pandas will try to convert as `int64` and transform values to 1, 2, 3 but for an unknown reason, it's not the case for the other file.